# Ember select not binding to a property in the model

Tags: ember.js

If I understand the ember.js documentation correctly then I should see the models systemStatus value get populated, but I'm not:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">         
        {{view "select" content=statuses value=model.systemStatus }}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  statuses: ["Being Built", "Active","Inactive"],
  selectedSystemStatus: 'Active',
  actions: {
    save: function() {
    //  this.model.set('systemStatus', this.selectedStatus);
        var s = this.get('selectedSystemStatus');
        this.model.save();
    },
    cancel: function() {

    }
  }
});
```

The model:

```
 import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Hello'}),
  systemStatus: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Active'}),
  description: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: 'Describe me'})
});
```

The router:
    import Ember from "ember";

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('software-system');
  }
});
```

Everything works up until you try to select an option from the UI.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and would like some help.

Comment: Try `this.get('content').save()`.

Comment: That didn't help.  The problem is that the model property is not being set from the select.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any place where you call `this.store.find('my-model')`? This is where the model gets populated.

The default way would be to put it into a corresponding `route` in the `model` hook:

```
// routes/my-model.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('my-model');
  }
});
```

With this approach, your controller will wait until the model is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, the router works. It's only when you try and use the select that it fails.